# multiplechoicefield - how to update the list of choices on each page load

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a multiplechoicefield shown here:

```
 ratesheets = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RATESHEET_CHOICES, allow_blank=False)
```

and RATESHEET_CHOICES is populated here (also showing the above in context):

```
class RatesheetsComparisonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    RATESHEET_CHOICES = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for rs in RateSheet.objects.all():
            self.RATESHEET_CHOICES.append((rs.pk, rs.title))
        super(RatesheetsComparisonSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

...

    ratesheets = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RATESHEET_CHOICES, allow_blank=False)
```

The only problem I'm having is that the MultipleChoiceField stays the same until I restart the server. How do I update the choices each time that I load the page. Do I need to put that same code somewhere else? It's taken me a long time to get here and I can't find anything about this kind of stuff that will seem to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `ratesheets` field not as a class variable (which are static!) but in the `__init__` method:

```
class RatesheetsComparisonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RatesheetsComparisonSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        RATESHIELD_CHOICES = []
        for rs in RateSheet.objects.all():
            RATESHEET_CHOICES.append((rs.pk, rs.title))
        self.fields['ratesheets'] = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=RATESHEET_CHOICES, allow_blank=False)
```

(I'm assuming these serializers work similar to Django forms, `self.fields` is a guess and that dictionary might be named differently)

**Edit: one more thing needed**

Change the Meta class from:

```
class Meta:
    model = RatesheetsComparison
    fields = ('created', 'ratesheets',)
    read_only_fields = ('created',)
```

to:

```
class Meta:
    model = RatesheetsComparison
    fields = ('created',)
    read_only_fields = ('created',)
```

or else you'll get an ImportError because it thought ratesheets existed but couldn't find it.

Comment: You were close...ish, I just had to do a few more things. You got me thinking if anything. I'll post my answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Never mind, you were super close, I just had to do one more thing.